# Cakephp - What is the best way to ensure flow unidirectional between actions?

Tags: cakephp

User registration in one of the websites I am working on is a multi-step process, requiring various actions from the same controller, and even from different controllers.

What is the best way to ensure that the user starts at the beginning of the process, and ensure that the user has completed step 1 before he can access step 2? I understand that new users won't know the URLs of these actions, but still.

Should I use session variables? Or maybe checking the referer at the beginning of each action?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Routes**

Firstly, since you mention multiple controllers, it may be worth considering creating routes to make the URLs for the registration process look user-friendly and flow well:

```
Router::connect('/register', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'register'));
Router::connect('/register/step1', array('controller' => 'profile', 'action' => 'add'));
Router::connect('/register/step2', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'verify'));
```

Once you have worked out the above, it should make the flow logic a bit clearer.

**Single controller action**

One of the most straight-forward approaches to wizards is to simply pass a `$step` parameter into your controller action:

```
public function register($step) {
    if ($step == 'profile') {
        // do stuff
        if ($hasProfile) {
           $this->redirect(array('verify'));
        }
    }
    if ($step == 'verify') {
        if (!$hasProfile) {
           return $this->redirect(array('profile'));
        }
        // do stuff
    }
    if ($step == 'done') {
        if (!$hasProfile) {
           return $this->redirect(array('profile'));
        }
        if (!$hasVerified) {
           return $this->redirect(array('verify'));
        }
        // do stuff
    }
    $this->redirect('profile'); // default step
}
```

This approach might not work for your application but it is worth thinking of the problem in it's simplest state before tackling it so you can keep down on any unneeded complexity.

**Session**

I would be tempted to use the user's session as a way of persisting which steps have been completed as it's not recommended to trust what you receive from the client. (The client submits their session ID with each request but the session storage is server-side). Exactly how you want to do this will depend on your implementation:

```
$this->Session->write('Auth.registration_step', '2');
```

One approach might be to store a step number and each action would

1. update step number and redirect on completion
2. enforce step number and redirect back to previous step if a user attempts to skip ahead.

It would be helpful to store the list of steps involved so each action can reuse the logic:

```
public function enforceRegistrationFlow() {
    $flow = array(
        1 => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'register'),
        2 => array('controller' => 'profile', 'action' => 'add'),
        3 => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'verify')
    );
    $step = $this->Session->read('Auth.registration_step');
    if ($flow[$step] !== /* current controller/action */) {
        $this->redirect($flow[$step]);
    }
}
```

Finally, there are some [wizard components](http://www.google.com/search?q=cakephp%20wizard%20component) of varying quality around that try to do the above for you, but I can't guarantee that they work (especially across multiple controllers) or that they will help you get the job done any quicker. :)

Comment: so are you saying that a session variable would be a safe way to do it? Thanks

Comment: Yes. As the session is stored on the server, the client can not write to this and progress past required steps. The worst they can do is delete the cookie storing their session ID, which means they lose all their progress.

Comment: I am about to implement this with session... Where should I write the function enforceRegistrationFlow()?? In the appController?? Thanks